# How to export mapStateToProps and Redux Form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm using Redux Form (ver. 6) for a log in page. What I would like to do is when the user fills out the form and clicks submit, grab the text from my state so that I can eventually dispatch an action with that email and password. However, I'm having trouble with exporting this component while using both connect from react-redux and Redux Form.

Using react-redux, connect wants to be exported like so when mapping state to props:

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LogInForm)

However, Redux Form wants it's export set up like this:

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'LogInForm',
  validate,
})(LogInForm);
```

Is there a way to combine these two? I'd tried something like:

```
const reduxFormConfig = reduxForm({
  form: 'LogInForm',
  validate,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxFormConfig)(LogInForm)
```

but it did not work.

Or Perhaps that's a better approach to handling this? Here is the full code from within my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import InputField from '../InputField';
import { validateLogInSignUp as validate } from '../../utils/validateForms.js';

const LogInForm = (props) => {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    pristine,
    submitting,
  } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field
          name="email"
          type="email"
          component={InputField}
          label="email"
        />
        <Field
          name="password"
          type="password"
          component={InputField}
          label="password"
        />
        <div>
          <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    loginInput: state.form,
  };
};

// export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LogInForm)

// export default reduxForm({
//  form: 'LogInForm',
//  validate,
// })(LogInForm);
```

Any and all help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `redux-form` you shouldn't need to access the state directly in your `LoginForm`. Instead, you should access the values in your parent component when the form is submitted:

```
// LoginForm.js
const LogInForm = (props) => {
  ...
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'LogInForm',
  validate,
})(LogInForm);


// Parent.js
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';

const handleSubmit = (values) => {
  alert(JSON.stringify(values));  // { email: 'foo@bar.com', password: '1forest1' }
};

const Parent = (props) => {
  return (
    <LoginForm onSubmit={ handleSubmit } />
  );
};
```

See https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/examples/simple/src/index.js#L42 for a more complete example of a simple form.

Comment: But what if the user refreshed the page ?! i still see that accessing reduxStore/state through reduxForm is important in some cases .

Comment: No, even in your example you shouldn't.

Answer (score 10):

There still a way to combine these two in reduxForm v6:

```
reduxForm({
  form: 'LogInForm',
  validate,
})(LogInForm);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LogInForm)
```

Here is how:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux

class LogInForm extends Component {
    ...
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { ... }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return { ... }
}

// First decorate your component with reduxForm
LogInForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'LogInForm',
  validate,
})(LogInForm);

// Then connect the whole with the redux store
export default connect(mapStateToProps, maDispatchToProps)(LogInForm)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this :

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux' ;
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class Example extends React.Component {
    ...
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { ... }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return { ... }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(reduxForm({
      form: 'formname',
      validate
})(Example));
```

Comment: Can you add a little explanation how your code snippet solves the issue? In this way your answer becomes more useful.

Comment: It should be the accepted answer, since it's the more simple way

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple threads with same issue. [I recently posted my take with my solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138158/uncaught-typeerror-this-props-signinuser-is-not-a-function/#answer-42353996) but with a few variations.

1. I used a class based component than a function based. I have found guides to specifically implement that way and explaining that the connect method of react-redux make it a Higher Order Component and as such it is best used with a class instance.
2. As mentioned by @doncredas, reduxForm and react-redux's connect method should be implemented separately, however, my implementation is as follows:

   ```
   function mapStateToProps(state) {
       return { form: state.form };
   }

   Signin = connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Signin);
   Signin = reduxForm({
    form: 'signin'
   })(Signin);
   export default Signin;
   ```

[Added later] Another variation can be:

```
const form = reduxForm({ form: 'signin' });
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(form(Signin));
```